# Why do universities offer full fund positions to international student?

Tags: graduate-admissions, international-students

Many top universities in north America accept international ph.d. students and pay their tuitions, insurnace and other funds. To get visa, international students should convince the officer that they will go back to their home countries. I am wondering why universities should accept international students and what are the benefits for universities and the destionation universities?

Comment: Why shouldn't they? It isn't quite a rant, but seems awfully close to it.

Comment: I am guessing that Amin ask this because the university fees are not cheap

Comment: Voted to reopen: this question asks about benefits for the University, while the "duplicate" is about positive and negative effects for the host country. University may have interests orthogonal to those of the country.

Answer (score 1):

Universities use Ph.D. students as teaching or research assistants. Essentially they are hiring you, with education being a part of payment. 
Moreover, if a Ph.D. student becomes a famous or at least succefull scientist, it is very good for image of a university.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why universities benefit from attracting talented students, including international students:

1. Students do not learn only from the lecturers, they also learn from each other. The more talented students are there in the classroom, the more all students can learn (given that the process is organised correctly). The more diverse the cohort is, the more opinions and viewpoints is there to share, discuss and benefit from. International students bring diversity of opinion, experience and talent.
2. The currency of academia is fame. Universities are in constant search for the very best research staff, who is likely to produce world-leading results and secure international fame and recognition for the University. Similarly, Universities strive for the very best students in hope that after the graduation, their alumni will eventually become internationally recognised figures is sciences, engineering, enterprise, charity sector, politics, sports, etc. The success of alumni brings recognition and fame also to their alma mater. Some of them also donate, considerably, for the rest of their life, to their Universities.
3. Best students are a great pleasure to teach, and a great challenge to teach. Excellent student body attracts excellent staff and keeps them happy, contributing to general academic health of the place.

Compared to the benefits (actual and potential) drawn from the talent of the best students (both international and local), a few $$$s for their tuition fees is the money very well spent.